# Оптимизация кода в рамках задачи «Коммерческий калькулятор»

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list, оптимизация

Всем здравствуйте! Есть код для решения задачи, но он не проходит по времени.

**Условие:**
Фирма OISAC выпустила новую версию калькулятора. Этот калькулятор берет с пользователя деньги за совершаемые арифметические операции. Стоимость каждой операции в долларах равна *5%* от числа, которое является результатом операции. На этом калькуляторе требуется вычислить сумму  натуральных чисел (числа известны). Нетрудно заметить, что от того, в каком порядке мы будем складывать эти числа, иногда зависит, в какую сумму денег нам обойдется вычисление суммы чисел (тем самым оказывается нарушен классический принцип “от перестановки мест слагаемых сумма не меняется”). Например, пусть нам нужно сложить числа `10`, `11`, `12` и `13`. Тогда если мы сначала сложим `10` и `11` (это обойдется нам в *1.05$*), потом результат с `12` (*1.65$*), и затем с `13` (*2.3$*), то всего мы заплатим **5$**. А если же сначала отдельно сложить `10` и `11` (*1.05$*), потом `12` и `13` (*1.25$*) и, наконец, сложить между собой два полученных числа (*2.3$*), то в итоге мы заплатим лишь **4.6$**.
Напишите программу, которая будет определять, за какую минимальную сумму денег можно найти сумму данных  чисел.

**Входные данные:**
Первая строка входных данных содержит число  (`2` ≤  ≤ `10**5`). Во второй строке заданы  натуральных чисел, каждое из которых не превосходит `10000`.

**Выходные данные:**
Определите, сколько денег нам потребуется на нахождения суммы этих  чисел. Результат должен быть выведен с двумя знаками после десятичной точки.

**Примеры:**

*Вход 1:*

```
4
10 11 12 13
```

*Выход 1:*

```
4.60
```

*Вход 2:*

```
2
1 1
```

*Выход 2:*

```
0.10
```

**Мой код:**

```
from bisect import *
from collections import deque

k = int(input())
B = sorted([int(_) for _ in input().split()])
A = deque()
A.extend(B)
cost = 0

while len(A) != 1:
    sum = A[0] + A[1]
    for _ in range(2): A.popleft()
    idx = bisect(A, sum)
    A.insert(idx, sum)
    cost += sum * 0.05
    print(cost)
    print(A)

print('%.2f'%cost)
```

Возможно, для ускорения работы, здесь нужно применить кучу (heap), но я не знаю, как можно это реализовать. Помогите, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Про кучу - верно, и описание её же есть в хелпе.

```
import heapq
a = [10, 11, 12, 13]
heapq.heapify(a)
sm = 0
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    x = heapq.heappop(a)
    y = heapq.heappop(a)
    s = x + y
    sm += s*0.05
    heapq.heappush(a, s)
print(sm)
```